# UITableView lagging when scrolling for chat like app

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a chat function in the app I am making. Each cell has a `UITextView` and I need to calculate the `**height and width**` of each cell. I do that and then cache that data.

Using NSLog I have determined that the data is correctly cached and the height for each row is only being asked for once.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    Message *message = [feedItems objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    NSString *reuseIdentifier;
    if (message.iSentThisMessage) {
        reuseIdentifier = @"MeCell";
    } else {
        reuseIdentifier = @"HostCell";
    }

    ChatTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:reuseIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    // Configure the cell...
    cell.textView.text = message.content;

    if (message.frame.size.height == 0 && message.frame.size.width == 0) {
        CGRect rect = cell.textView.frame;
        rect.origin.x = 5;
        rect.origin.y = 3;
        CGSize size = [self text:message.content
                    sizeWithFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:17.0]
               constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(225.0, CGFLOAT_MAX)];
        rect.size.height = size.height
                            + cell.textView.textContainerInset.bottom
                            + cell.textView.textContainerInset.top;
        rect.size.width = [cell.textView sizeThatFits:CGSizeMake(225.0, rect.size.height)].width
                            + cell.textView.textContainerInset.left
                            + cell.textView.textContainerInset.right;

        if (message.iSentThisMessage) {
            rect.origin.x = 320 - (rect.origin.y + rect.size.width);
        }

        cell.textView.frame = rect;
        message.frame = rect;
        NSLog(@"Not Cached :(");
    } else {
        cell.textView.frame = message.frame;
        NSLog(@"Cached!");
    }

    return cell;
}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    Message *message = [feedItems objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    CGSize size = [self text:message.content
                sizeWithFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:17.0]
           constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(225.0, CGFLOAT_MAX)];

    if (indexPath.row + 1 == feedItems.count)
        size.height += 4;

    NSLog(@"Height asked for.");
    return size.height + 12;
}
```

Also, one other possibility may be that I am overriding the following method in my custom `uitableviewcell` class because otherwise it rearranges the contents of my cell.

```
- (void) layoutSublayersOfLayer:(CALayer *)layer {

}
```

I can't seem to figure out how to make it not lag!!

Comment: Take the sizing logic out of `cellForRowAtIndexPath`. You shouldn't need it there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not clear why you're using a text view, but you should change to a label if you can.

Also, don't cache the height in your table delegate method, that's a nasty side effect. Calculate the height up front, either when the message is loaded / received, or on a background thread for batch load.

The text view / label frame should also be relative to the cell, either by auto resizing / layout. So you should never set it explicitly.

On top of that - profile using instruments. This is the only thing that will really tell you what's wrong.